# Azure App Service dotnet core 2.2 - HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webapps

> I have found a work around for this issue, and that is to turn of
>   application insights in the app service blade, or to set the
>   Application insights/Collection level to disabled (shown as basic
>   under .Net)

When I deployed my webb app to azure it would not start and gave the following error.
HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

**I looked at the eventlog.xml** 
- Kudo > Debug Console > "LogFiles"/eventlog.xml
and the error is a dependency injection error, unable to resolve Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer (see full message in the end)

**I turned on debugging in web.config**  (it gave the same level of information as eventlog)

After reading other threads on stackoverflow and  blogs etc **I validated that the runtime versions of dotnet core was correct** (kudo > cmd > "dotnet --info")
and **validated the appsettings.json files** as many have reported an issue with broken configs causing the same error (I have also verified this behavior)

Somewhere I read that application insights could cause this (but it was in the end of the Friday and I forgot to save the resource) and then I tried to disable App insigths from the app service blade and it solves my problem, but I don't understand why and would like to know if I can change the startup config (tried to UseKestrel as this was the solution in some cases when not using the setup I have.

```
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration
```

Without having tested this I'm thinking that .UseApplicationInsights() in startup could be in conflict with the changes Azure apply in the app when turning on app insights from the app service.

**Error message in logs.**

```
      Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
    Unable to resolve type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer, service name:  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unresolved dependency [Target Type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer], [Parameter: transportFactory(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory)], [Requested dependency: 
ServiceType:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, ServiceName:] ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 
Unresolved dependency [Target Type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory], [Parameter: applicationLifetime(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime)],
[Requested dependency: ServiceType:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime, ServiceName:]
```

**Can anyone explain how to understand why this error occur?** 
I have seen many explanations for the error code on local(windows) IIS servers, but haven't yet found one for when hosting in Azure.

Thanks!

At least I do hope my question and work around can help =)

As I had to walk through Jenkins, Octopus deploy, Azure where I hadn't configured anything on my own it took really too long time, I did cry only on the inside ;-)

Comment: forgot to mention that if I deployed the application as "Self-Contained" it did work when application insights was on.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but we bumped into this recently too. The bad news is that this error is not very descriptive and can mean lots of things. In our case it was a permission issue. When the application started it tried to connect to Azure Key Vault, but the service principal didn't have the rights to access it. A wild guess would be that perhaps it has something to do with App Insights, maybe the instrumentation key is not correct or something similar. If you connect to Kudu and try starting the app manually by simply running dotnet xxx.dll you might get a better error description.

Comment: thanks @ayls I did all the troubleshooting tips I could find, and I didn't get any error when starting the app from cmd in Kudo - I might try out the permission Idea, if it is something with the key vault, the instrumentation key was correct but I don't know at the moment if there could be something with the key vault anyway. thanks for your thoughts